# Converting from ascii to utf-8 format - iconv not working

Tags: solaris, unicode

I have a requirement to convert from ASCII text format to UTF-8.

Below is what I am performing through the `iconv` command:

```
[root@main tmp]# cat File1
1
5
6
[root@main tmp]# file File1
File1: ASCII text
[root@main tmp]# iconv -f ascii -t utf-8 File1 > File2
[root@main tmp]# file File2
File2: ASCII text
```

(Still ASCII not utf-8)

Any suggestions on how to convert it from ascii to utf-8?

Comment: ASCII 127 is a subset of utf-8. see [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8)

Comment: Indeed, "cp" is an efficient ASCII to UTF-8 converter.

Comment: Your ASCII file *is* already in UTF-8. What are you trying to do?

Answer (score 5):

Two things that are relevant here:

1. the stock `file` utility on Solaris sucks
2. 7-bit ASCII characters are byte compatibly included in UTF-8. That means that when your input file just contains 7-bit ASCII characters no actual conversion takes place. And even a good `file` utility would display ASCII.

Thus, you probably want to convert a file in some sort of 'extended' 8 byte ASCII encoding. For example [latin1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859). Then you have to specify it with iconv, e.g.:

```
$ iconv -f latin1 -t utf8 file1 > file2
```

You then can compare the output like this:

```
$ cmp file1 file2
$ hexdump ...
$ $EDITOR file2
```

Editors like vim provide some commands to look at the byte values of certain characters, change the used encoding on the fly etc.

Answer (score 1):

Should you really want `file` to state your ASCII file is UTF-8, which it is already anyway, you can run this command which prepends an UTF-8 [BOM (Byte Order Mark)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark) to it:

```
(printf "\357\273\277";cat File1) > File2
```

Edit: a couple of issues though:

- This will work with the find version usually provided with Linux distributions but Solaris `file` won't detect the file as UTF-8 but just "data"
- The BOM might confuse tools used to process the text file