# OpenSSL converting chars to UTF-8 literals

Tags: openssl, unicode

I'm running a simple PKI web application in Php that uses OpenSSL shell commands and stores information in a text database. I have to deal with non-ASCII input characters (eg. German) but when a new cert is created, the fields turn into

```
[...] /C=DE/ST=H\xC3\xA4mburg/L=H\xC3\xA4mburg/O=\xC3\x9FBCD/OU=\xC3\xA4BC/ [...]
```

I've added

```
[req]
utf8                = yes
string_mask         = utf8only
name_opt            = multiline,-esc_msb,utf8
```

to the OpenSSL config files, and the certs are created using

```
openssl req -utf8 [...]
openssl ca -utf8 [...]
```

The program writes out temporary config files used to request and create the user cert. I've checked and the fields in the user config file are fine, as well as in the CA's. The problem appears when OpenSSL creates the certificates. The database and the certs contain these codes instead of the correct characters.

I also tried to convert the database file to UTF-8 using `iconv` but the file remains in US-ASCII format. [This approach](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/86092/156197) changes what `file --mime-encoding` outputs to utf-8, but OpenSSL continues to write new entries the same way as before.

I'll also mention I'm sending the utf-8 header and setting `AddDefaultCharset utf-8` in virtualhosts. The locale is set to `de_DE.utf8` in the code and on the server.

What am I missing? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Have you an solution?

Comment: I'll just point out that as long as `utf8 = yes`/`-utf8` is set, and the local `LANG` variable is correct in the terminal. The certificate will be created with the correct formatting. The output of `openssl x509 -noout -text` however, does not handle interpretation of UTF8 characters outside of A-Z, there for certain chars will become `\C3\A4` for instance, but viewed in a browser they'll look perfectly fine.

Answer (score 4):

I was struggling with this for days aswell, finally got it working.

`-utf8` on the commandline and `utf8 = yes` in the config seems a bit redundant.

I used `-utf8 -nameopt multiline,utf8` on the commandline, i did'nt escape anything in the config file (I tried several versions of that but none worked) which says **UTF-8 Unicode text** when i run `file <configfile>`.

My locale and cli are configured to use utf-8 input and output, config is similar to:

```
[req]
prompt = no
distinguished_name = subject

[subject]
C = DE
ST = myutf8state
L = myutf8locality
O = myutf8organization
OU = myutf8organizational unit
CN = my.common.name
```

I found these 2 questions on stackoverflow to be of help:

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16478452/how-to-create-csr-with-utf8-subject-in-openssl#29649477
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23598872/how-to-create-ssl-certificate-with-unicode-characters-in-the-organization-name